# why Java still finds old method even though I updated the transitive library to a newer version?

Tags: java, mule, nosuchmethoderror

I need to migrate a third party library in a project - let's call it `MyProject`.

`MyProject ---uses---> Enterprise library A ---uses---> mule-core v3.4`

I'm using Maven and I excluded all mule dependencies from library A, replacing it with `mule-core` v3.9 instead. Still, even if the fat jar that's generated contains only `mule-core` v3.9, I still see that the application loads an old version of the `org.mule.util.AttributeEvaluator` class.

It seems that this class, in `mule-core v3.4` used to contain the following method:

```
public void initialize(final ExpressionManager expressionManager)
```

In mule-core 3.9, the method changed its signature to the following:

```
public AttributeEvaluator initialize(final ExpressionManager expressionManager)
```

Because of this change, the enterprise library A fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mule.util.AttributeEvaluator.initialize(
   Lorg/mule/api/expression/ExpressionManager;)V
```

The only solution that I found to be working was to bring the source code of Enterprise Library A into the source code of my project and to compile it again with the correct dependency to `mule-core v3.9`, but I'm sure that there is a better way.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Where are you deploying the fat jar?

Comment: Seems not as if the old version get loaded. Seems as if your `Enterprise library A` tries to call the `void` method which does not exist in new version. That's why the `NoSuchMethodError`. In byte code the return type is part of the method signature. So your `Enterprise library A` is not compatible with the `mule-core 3.9`.

Comment: @AxelRichter That would explain it, indeed. So, the only solution that I have is to upgrade the Enterprise library A to use Mule 3.9 ?

Comment: @pringi The application is a spring boot application, so it has Tomcat embedded.

Comment: Re compiling of `Enterprise library A` against the new  `mule-core 3.9` leads to use the new `public AttributeEvaluator initialize(final ExpressionManager expressionManager)` as each method can be used as it it would return `void`.

Comment: Why is the application using that internal method? What is it using it for?